# Java Card Layout with Background Image

Tags: java, swing, awt, background-image, cardlayout

I am creating a Flight Reservation system for a project, having trouble with the GUI of the app. I am using a CardLayout to manage the multiple cards for this program.

In the login card I am trying to add a background image, but the input fields are shown below the image.

The code for the program is

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.imageio.*;
    import java.net.*;

    public class CardPanel {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                CardLayout cardLayout = null;
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);

                URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/P59NF.png");
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
                JLabel logo = new JLabel(imageIcon);

                JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
                JButton login = new JButton("Login");
                buttonsPanel.add(login);

                contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 15));

                contentPane.add(logo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                contentPane.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

                frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

A screenshot of the app is also attached (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkEcz.png).

I would like the button to be above the background image.

Comment: _but the input fields are shown below the image_ So where & how should they appear?

Comment: @Reimeus I wanted the image as a background and the input fields above it.

Comment: Try to recreate this with two panels in the card layout, each with a single component. One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - is the card layout actually related to the immediate problem? It appears from the screenshot that the image is pushing components downward in a single panel (without card layout. Focus carefully on the *problem* code rather than dump the entire code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've updated the code to only include the relevant parts, however, was unable to hot link the image. I appreciate your advice and help.

Comment: *"however, was unable to hot link the image."* Use one of the images in the page I linked to, **that's what they're for!** Also load the image direct from URL.

Comment: @AndrewThompson done

Comment: A test suggests a card layout cannot be used to show a BG image. It seems that internally it removes one card and adds another when swapping components. Use a custom painted `JPanel` to draw the BG image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test suggests a card layout cannot be used to show a BG image. It seems that internally it removes one card and adds another when swapping components. Use a custom painted `JPanel` to draw the BG image.

Here is the evidence.

[image]

That red color is the panel with the card layout, the button panel is set to be transparent.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class CardPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);

        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg"));
        JLabel logo = new JLabel(imageIcon);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        buttonsPanel.add(login);

        buttonsPanel.setOpaque(false);

        contentPane.add(logo, "logo");
        contentPane.add(buttonsPanel, "button");

        cardLayout.show(contentPane, "button");

        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```